# How to EXECUTE IMMEDIATE output of DBMS_METADATA.GET_DEPENDENT_DLL?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I would like to obtain all the GRANTS of an OBJECT with GET_DEPENDENT_DLL, drop the object and then be able to use EXECUTE IMMEDIATE to GRANT it again all its previous privileges.

To obtain the GRANTS for MYOBJECT I do something along these lines:

```
DECLARE
    get_grants VARCHAR2(300) := 'SELECT DBMS_METADATA.GET_DEPENDENT_DDL (''OBJECT_GRANT'', :object_name, :owner) from dual';
    grants_obtained VARCHAR(30000);                                                   
BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE get_grants INTO grants_obtained USING 'MYOBJECT', 'MYSCHEMA';   
END;
```

This returns something similar to:

> GRANT QUERY REWRITE ON "MYSCHEMA"."MYOBJECT" TO "SCHEMA1" WITH GRANT OPTION
>
> GRANT EXECUTE ON "MYSCHEMA"."MYOBJECT" TO "SCHEMA2" WITH GRANT OPTION
>
> GRANT FLASHBACK ON "MYSCHEMA"."MYOBJECT" TO "SCHEMA3" WITH GRANT OPTION

The results are not formatted in a way EXECUTE IMMEDIATE can process them. If I try to run them with EXECUTE IMMEDIATE it fails:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE grants_obtained;
```

Throws:

> ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

**Is there way a way to obtain the GRANTS for an OBJECT using GET_DEPENDENT_DLL and be able to run them with EXECUTE IMMEDIATE?**

Comment: Why do you not simply write `get_grants VARCHAR2(300) := DBMS_METADATA.GET_DEPENDENT_DDL ('OBJECT_GRANT', 'MYOBJECT', 'MYSCHEMA');`?

Comment: @Wernfried I dont understand your suggestion.

Comment: @Dzyann, there is no reason in PL/SQL to call a function by `SELECT ... FROM dual;`A simple assignment with `:=` does the same, is easier to read and avoids context switching (in many times). Also there is no need in your case to execute a dynamic statement - static is sufficient.

Comment: @Wernfried thanks! I did not know that, I have changed my script to use your advice. Thanks again! I was confused because the get_grants variable is the one use to save the dynamic SQL not the results of the GET_DEPENDENT_DDL call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell `dbms_metadata` to generate a terminator. This can be done using the procedure `set_transform_param`

```
dbms_metadata.set_transform_param(dbms_metadata.SESSION_TRANSFORM, 'SQLTERMINATOR', true);
```

So your PL/SQL Block becomes:

```
DECLARE
    get_grants VARCHAR2(300) := 'SELECT DBMS_METADATA.GET_DEPENDENT_DDL (''OBJECT_GRANT'', :object_name, :owner) from dual';
    grants_obtained CLOB;                                                   
BEGIN
    dbms_metadata.set_transform_param(dbms_metadata.SESSION_TRANSFORM, 'SQLTERMINATOR', true);
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE get_grants INTO grants_obtained USING 'MYOBJECT', 'MYSCHEMA';   
END;
/
```

More details in the manual: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/d_metada.htm#BGBJBFGE

---

Edit:

Even when you configure `dbms_metadata` to add the `;` you can't run those statements using `execute immediate`.

`execute immediate` can only run a single statement at a time. I can think of only two things that you can do:

1. parse the returned SQL and split it up into individual statements (for "only" grants this might not be so hard)
2. Spool the output into a script and then run that script from within SQL*Plus.

Comment: I think the OP is trying to `execute immediate grants_obtained;`, though that isn't actually shown in the question; but that still won't work as you can't have multiple statements in a single dynamic call.

Comment: @AlexPoole yes you are right, isn't it clear on my question? how would you suggest I update my question so it is clear? Thanks!

Comment: @Dzyann - edit your question to show the code that actually throws the ORA-00933; at the moment you show that you're retrieving the `grants_obtained` value, but not what you do with it.

Comment: I had to set the terminator like this dbms_metadata.set_transform_param(dbms_metadata.SESSION_TRANSFORM, 'SQLTERMINATOR', true); It didnt work when i tried to pass ';' as parameter.

Comment: I would like to accept your answer, I just see one thing wrong in the final PL/SQL block you didn't correct the call to set_transform_param. I tried editing it myself, but it seems it got rejected.

Answer (score 3):

Change:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE grants_obtained;
```

To:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'create schema authorization MYSCHEMA '||grants_obtained;
```

[CREATE SCHEMA](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_6016.htm#SQLRF01313) can run multiple grant statements without terminators between the grants.